# How to make Javascript/Jquery/AJAX wait before the code is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have this piece of code in my html template. It checks the name of the school that the user enters against the unique ID that the school has associated to it in my database.

```js
$("#id_school").change(function() {
  var school = $(this).val();
  var identification_code = document.getElementById('id_identification_code')

  if (identification_code != '' and school != '') {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/checks/validate_school/',
      data: {
        'school': school,
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('Checked School')
        if (data.code != identification_code) {
          console.log(data.code);
          document.getElementById('id_school').style.borderColor = 'red';
          document.getElementById('id_identification_code').style.borderColor = 'red';

        } else {
          document.getElementById('id_school').style.borderColor = 'green';
          document.getElementById('id_identification_code').style.borderColor = 'green';
        }

      }
    });
  }
});
```

As you can see, if the code in the database and the code the user enters don't match, I want the box to go red. When they do, I want it to go green.

The problem is, as soon as I enter in the schools name, both boxes go red, before I have entered in the code. I tried fixing this with `if(identification_code != '' and school != '')` but this didnt work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You miss a `val()` in `id_identification_code` selector

Comment: `if (identification_code != '' and school != '') {` First `identification_code` is a DOM Element object, so will never equal `''`. Presumably you mean `identification_code.value != ''`. Also `and` is not valid syntax in JS. You need `&&` instead

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have made the changes, but now nothing happens. The outline doesn't change colour, and nothing gets logged in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use identification_code.value as it is DOM element.

```
if(identification_code.value != '' && school != ''){
......
}
```

Comment: what about in ajax success?

Comment: @charlietfl same  if (data.code != identification_code.value) { ...}

Comment: Made the changes but now nothing happens. The Colour of the boxes dont change, and nothing is logged in the console @SubhabrataMondal

Comment: you can use blur() instead of change()

Comment: blur() works after losing focus from the that input box. Type something and get out the focus from that box and check it is working or not..

Comment: Still doesnt change after I tab out of the input box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146859/discussion-between-wtreston-and-subhabrata-mondal).

Answer (score 1):

```
var identification_code = document.getElementById('id_identification_code')
```

`identification_code` here is not a text but your html element, It will never be `''`.

you should use the Logical And operator (&&) here:

```
if(identification_code != '' and school != '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery.Deferred() for sequential execution in Jquery.

```
var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
```

or

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
```

**Once created, the Deferred object exposes several methods. Ignoring those deprecated or removed, they are:**

- always(callbacks[, callbacks, ..., callbacks]): Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is either resolved or rejected.
- done(callbacks[, callbacks, ..., callbacks]): Add handlers to be
  called when the Deferred object is resolved.
- fail(callbacks[, callbacks, ..., callbacks]): Add handlers to be
  called when the Deferred object is rejected.
- notify([argument, ..., argument]): Call the progressCallbacks on a
  Deferred object with the given arguments.
- notifyWith(context[, argument, ..., argument]): Call the
  progressCallbacks on a Deferred object with the given context and
  arguments.
- progress(callbacks[, callbacks, ..., callbacks]): Add handlers to be
  called when the Deferred object generates progress notifications.
- promise([target]): Return a Deferred‘s Promise object.
- reject([argument, ..., argument]): Reject a Deferred object and call any failCallbacks with the given arguments.
- rejectWith(context[, argument, ..., argument]): Reject a Deferred
  object and call any failCallbacks with the given context and
  arguments.
- resolve([argument, ..., argument]): Resolve a Deferred object and call any doneCallbacks with the given arguments.
- resolveWith(context[, argument, ..., argument]): Resolve a Deferred
  object and call any doneCallbacks with the given context and
  arguments.
- state(): Determine the current state of a Deferred object.
- then(resolvedCallback[, rejectedCallback[, progressCallback]]): Add
  handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected,
  or still in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to fix my problem. Rather than looking at the school name field, I looked at the Identification Code field, and only run the code when this was filled out. Here is my new code:

```
$('#id_identification_code').blur(function(){
var school_code = $(this).val();
var school_name = document.getElementById('id_school').value;

$.ajax(
    {
        url: '/checks/validate_school/',
        data: {
            'name':school_name,
        },
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(data){
            if(data.code == school_code){
                console.log('Codes Match')                    
                document.getElementById('id_school').style.borderColor='green';
                document.getElementById('id_identification_code').style.borderColor='green';                    
            }else{
                console.log('Codes do not match')
                document.getElementById('id_school').style.borderColor='red';
                document.getElementById('id_identification_code').style.borderColor='red'; 
            }

        }

    }
)

})
```